# I didn't added dependency for androidx CoordinatorLayout and RecyclerView Library but still able to use it

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

In my project I never added this dependency

`implementation androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout` but i am still able to use `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in my `activity_main.xml`.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.beats"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    //Google material design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now I don't understand how am I able to use the `CoordinatorLayout` in my layout without declaring specified dependency for it.

Comment: Because `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` includes `CoordinatorLayout` no need to add other `dependencies` for `CoordinatorLayout`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I didn't added dependency for androidx CoordinatorLayoutLibrary but stil able to use it

Because you have added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Which includes `CoordinatorLayout` inside it

No need to add other `dependencies` for `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Does the material library add the latest version of recyclerview in my project or i have to add it manually

Comment: @VivekSingh `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` includes `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0`  you can check here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material/1.0.0

Comment: I can see the cardview and appcompat artifact in the compile dependencies section of the maven repository page, so does that means that they also comes with the android material dependency.

Comment: @VivekSingh yes

Comment: But i can't see the CoordinatorLayout artifact in the section

Comment: @VivekSingh yes that is not mentioned there, [the `CoordinatorLayout` is one of the components of Android Design Support Library](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

`com.google.android.material` uses `androidx.recyclerview` and a plethora of other libraries as transitive dependencies, meaning you don't have to manually import them, adding the `com.google.android.material` dependency is enough.